# Pass parameter as query string to kendo datasource create method

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm, kendo-datasource

**Scenario :** consider we have two view-models use same data source `masterDataSource`, and we want to add a `detail` entity to `master` entity.

**Question :** how would you pass `masterId` as query string to the create method of datasource from those view-models:

```js
var masterDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        create: {
            url: function() {
                return "/api/master/addItem?masterId=" + masterId;//<-- How to pass masterId form view-models
            },
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST"
        },
    },

    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "id"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "post body".  You mean you want to post some data instead of passing it on the query string?

Comment: Have you tried data:yourjsonobject

Comment: @RickS I have no problem to pass the data to datasource the actual problem is how i pass `masterId` to `url` from two view-models.

Comment: That confused me because your code doesn't show any attempt to use your view models.  Are you asking how to get masterId from your view model and pass it on the query string?

Comment: @RickS actually i don't want get `masterId` from view model and don't want data source depend on view-model. I want the view-models pass the `masterId` to data source. So I can have many view-models use the data source.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/detailtemplate.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this solution:

```js
var dynamicUrl = "/api/master/addItem?masterId=" + masterId;
masterDataSource.transport.options.read.url = dynamicUrl;
```